# Where is my mistake? Checking if password is correct in Python

Tags: python

I am new in Python and programming. I am trying to make a program that verifies that the entered password has a certain format. I was pretty sure my code was correct, but obviously...it's not. It won't exit the while loop when the password is in the correct format.
Where is my mistake? Thank you all for your patience!

```
low = ['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']
up = ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']
cr = ['@$%&']
digito = ['0123456789']
counter1 = 0
tries = True
while tries:
    length = False
    May = False
    Minus = False
    Num = False
    Char = False
    counter1 += 1
    password = input('Password: ')
    if len(password) > 7 and len(password) < 16:
        length = True
    for caracter in password:
        if caracter in low:
            Minus = True
        if caracter in up:
            May = True
        if caracter in cr:
            Char = True
        if caracter in digito:
            Num = True
    if length and May and Minus and Num and Char:
        print('Password ok.')
        passw = password
        tries = False
    if counter1 == 5:
        print('You had 5 attemps.')
        break
```

Comment: Don't just show us your code, show us the specific problem or error that causes you to think that code isn't already correct.

Comment: Also, code should be a [mre] -- the **shortest possible** code that causes the same problem. Assuming luk2302's answer is correct (which it looks to be), that could be just two lines. First line: `low = ['abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']`; second line `print("a" in low)`; question text "why is a letter saying it's not in the lower-case set?"

Comment: Have you tried to run the code and debug?  Try this visual platform - https://pythontutor.com/   you may find the reason.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand my mistake. I just didn't where it was, and since it was a short code I thought it was better to show it complete.  Sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that when you check:

```
"A" in ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']
```

it returns False. This is because the list `['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']` does not contain the element `"A"`. Try to replace the top 4 line with the following code and see if it works:

```
low = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
up = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
cr = '@$%&'
digito = '0123456789'
```

Answer (score 4):

`low`, `up`, `cr` and `digito` should all be strings, not a list with only one string in it: `low = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'`. Otherwise only literally `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` is in `low`, not `"a"`.

Answer (score 1):

Each list should contain separate letters instead of an entire string of the alphabet.
For example, instead of writing

```
up = ['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ']
```

you should write

```
up = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'...]
```

A better version of your code might be the following:

```
tries = True
up = False
low = False
special = False
counter = 0
while tries:
    counter += 1
    
    if counter == 5:
        print('You had 5 attemps.')
        break
        
    password = input("Enter your password: ")
    if len(password) > 7 and len(password) < 16:
        for char in password:
            if char.upper() == char:
                up = True
            if char.lower() == char:
                low = True
            if (ord(char) >= 35 and ord(char) <= 38) or ord(char) == 64:
                special = True
                
        if up and low and special:
                tries = False
                print("Password ok")
```